# Possible scam using Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-apps-script

Is there any possibility of someone harvesting email address and/or Google profile info by sharing a link to a file on Google drive and collecting info on the people who view the file?

I suspect a scam is involved and want to verify if it a possibility?

I am open to any options, including one using scripting.

I am part of a online forum, and a user is constantly sharing links to files hosted on Google Drive, which aren't really relevant to the discussion. He is definitely trolling. My question is, is it possible he is also trying to harvest email addresses or other user info for spamming purposes?

Comment: Can some advise why the downvote? If this is off topic, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of account the document owner has (work or school) it would be possible for them to see a list of people who have opened the document.  But I don't think it includes any links to their profile or their email address.

[You are also able to opt-out of your history being displayed](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7378739):

1. Open Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides
2. At the top left, click Menu -> Settings
3. Under "Activity dashboard," turn off Show your view history